# changing starred caption without affecting unstarred caption

Tags: floats, captions

Given the table

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \caption{Test table}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \toprule
        abc &   def &   ghi     \\ \midrule
        abc1    &   def2    &   ghi3    \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \caption*{Source: xyz}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I change the space before and after the starred caption (from the `caption` package) without affecting the unstarred caption?
And is this possible for any (un)starred command to be changed without affecting the other?

Comment: Are you more looking for a footnote in the table than a second unnumbered caption?

Comment: It is kind of a footnote, yes. But it should be the same font, size etc. as the text of the caption above the table and it should be usable inside all kind of floats (table, figure and a float generated by me with Koma called [eq](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/602891/244141), which the starred caption provided

Comment: Do you mean horizontal space or vertical space? Maybe `\end{tabular}\\[2mm]Source: xyz\end{table}` would suffice? This works also for figures, and possibly also for your custom float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In combination with [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/52009/244141) answer I added a command to change `abovecaptionskip` and `belowcaptionskip` inside a group to save the both previous lengths as well as restore them afterwards:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[%
font=small,%
labelfont=bf,%
justification=justified,%
singlelinecheck=false,%
format=plain]{caption}%

\newcommand{\source}[1]{Source: #1}%
\newcommand{\captionskip}[1]{%
    \begingroup%
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt plus 2pt}%
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt plus 2pt}%
    \caption*{\source{#1}}%
    \par\endgroup%
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \centering
        \caption{Test table}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \toprule
            abc &   def &   ghi     \\ \midrule
            abc1    &   def2    &   ghi3    \\ \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \captionskip{Test}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```